# How to set up svn to automatically export to public_html?

Tags: linux, svn, export, triggers, post-commit

I'm just getting started with svn so please, help me out if I saw anything stupid.

I'm developing on a windows laptop using tortoisesvn.
I'm deploying to a linux server.

I have my repo set up and checked out on my laptop.
**I can't manage to check it out to a directory on the server.** I've created a directory for it but can't get `svn checkout file:///...` to work! Based on [this tutorial](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/misc/svn01/) the `checkout` command takes the following form: `svn checkout file:///repository_name/project/trunk project` but **what is the** `repository_name`**?** My repo is at `/home/username/svn`, I don't remember naming the repo other than saying what directory it's in.

Once I do actually have that sorted I would like to have the repo automatically export to that directory when I commit from my laptop. **Is that possible?**

Sorry if that's horribly unclear but I wanted to be detailed.

**Basically I want to commit from my laptop and have that trigger an export of the newly commited files to a directory on the server.**

Comment: You have to create a batch file with svnexport and a copy command.

Comment: Looks like you're asking the same question over and over.

Comment: @powtac Windows dev machine, Linux server
@Eric Granted, I've asked a lot of questions about svn today but they've not been the same. I'd like the answers to actually be about the question I've asked each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different ways you can automatically export to your public_html folder, both of which involve setting up a post-commit hook.  You could:

1. Setup a [post-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) that will run on your Windows laptop and copy the necessary files to your server, perhaps through `scp` (available in the [Putty suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)), rsync, or even a [samba file share](http://www.samba.org/).
2. Setup your Linux-server to host your repository so that it has full access to the filesystem on which your public_html folder exists, and then setup a post-commit hook that copies the necessary files to your public_html folder.  Of course, you would need to checkout from the Linux repository instead of the one on your laptop, but it might be worth it.

Now, a couple of things you've stated above are a bit... confusing.  I've made some assumptions that reconcile the above, so please comment if I have mis-assumed.

Right now, you have both the repository and a checkout on your laptop.  And, it sounds like you have used the `file://` protocol for your checkout. If so, you **will not be able to access your repository from your Linux server** (yes, it is possible **if** you're also serving your repository over SSH or http).  This would explain why you can't get a checkout using the same file protocol within Linux -- *it doesn't have access to your Windows file system.*

Given the above, I would try approach number one above. Write a script (or program) that copies the files to your Linux server.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [**this discussion**](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-636663.html) on Ubuntuforums helps (provided your repo and web server are running on Linux). It explains the concept of Post Commit Hooks, and shows actual example scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a copy of your svn coment to a directory where you can view it (as opposed to actually *working on it*), you should use the `svn export` command.